# Background image not appearing in CSS, but works in img tag

Tags: html, css

I have an img tag which shows an image. This comes up fine. In the same file i have a div with a class having a background image with same url and same file. The img works but not the CSS background.

```
<img src="../../Content/Themes/Default/images/DeleteIcon.jpg" />

#droptarget
{
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    content:'Drop here to Delete';
    background: url('../../Content/Themes/Default/images/DeleteIcon.jpg') no-repeat 140px 102px;
}
```

Comment: Use `0 0` instead of `140px 102px`

Comment: How come you have an x and y offset of 140px and 102px?

Comment: you are defining the box with smaller height and width then your image height/width (100px on 100px vs image 140px on 102px).

Comment: @KarelG that's not the image size it's the background-position property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `0 0` as background position:
jsFiddle:[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDmmy/)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your x and y coordinate offset. Its pushing it out of the div.

```
 background: url('../../Content/Themes/Default/images/DeleteIcon.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also using `background-image` and `background-repeat` like this:

```
#droptarget {
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    content:'Drop here to Delete';
    background-image: url('../../Content/Themes/Default/images/DeleteIcon.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And if you have `background-position` inherited from other element, you can add:

```
#droptarget {
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    content:'Drop here to Delete';
    background-image: url('../../Content/Themes/Default/images/DeleteIcon.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: `background` is a shortcut for all of these!

Comment: You are right `background` regroup (color, image, repeat, and position), but sometimes the element inherit position from other element using `background-position`